# From a hash with array elements, how can I find the key for a particular array value?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Every value of my hash is an array:

```
tab_details = {
  'ex1' => ['1', '2']
}
```

I want to pass an element and get the key that corresponds to an array that has the element.

This is one way to do so:

```
tab_details.each{|k, v|
  return key = k if tab_details[k].include? '1'
}
```

Is there any other optimal way to handle this?

Comment: Note that in Ruby `1 != '1'`.

Comment: Can multiple arrays have same element?

Comment: @Jagdeep Singh No

Comment: @Amadan Made the change in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (not so direct) way of doing this can be to *invert* the Hash by *expanding* each array to make each element a key:

```
tab_details = {
  'foo' => [2, 3, 5],
  'bar' => [1, 4, 6]
}
# => {"foo"=>[2, 3, 5], "bar"=>[1, 4, 6]}

inverted_hash = tab_details.each_with_object({}) do |(k, ary), out|
                  ary.each { |elem| out[elem] = k }
                end
# => {2=>"foo", 3=>"foo", 5=>"foo", 1=>"bar", 4=>"bar", 6=>"bar"}

input = 1
inverted_hash[input]
# => "bar"
```

Now, of course, it assumes that the `input` and array elements are of **same type** i.e. Integer. You can convert them acc. to what is given in your question:

```
# If all the array elements are strings
inverted_hash[input.to_s]
# => "bar"
```

Another assumption it makes is, that **no** element is present in *more than one array*.

Comment: The OP did not say whether the given element could appear in more than one hash value (array), so I don't think you need the assumption given in your last sentence. If the OP regards the keys ordered and wants the first key that has the given element in the key's value you need to invert the hash in such a way that the values (former keys) are in reverse key order. Perhaps use [Enumerable#reverse_each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan) in that case.

Comment: This would be the best approach if the method were called frequently.

Comment: Modifying the method a little bit so that it returns all the keys that has the particular value.

`inverted_hash = tab_details.each_with_object({}) do |(k, ary), out|
      ary.each { |elem| 
       if out[elem].nil?
        out[elem] = []
       end
       out[elem].push k
      }
end`

Answer (score 1):

```
tab_details.find { |_,v| v.include?("1") }&.first
  #=> "ex1"

tab_details.find { |_,v| v.include?("cat") }&.first
  #=> nil
```

`&` is the [Safe Navigation Operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/). In the second example above the block returns `nil` so, because of the SNO, `first` is not executed and `nil` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use detect method

```
 k, v = tab_details.detect{ |_,v| v.include?("1") }

 p k
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> tab_details = {"ex1"=>["1", "2"], "ex2"=>["3", "4", "5"], "ex3"=>["2", "1", "9"]}
> tab_details.select{|k,v| v.include? "1"}.keys
#=> ["ex1", "ex3"]
```

to check against **integer** convert array elements to integer using `map(&:to_i)`

```
> tab_details.select{|k,v| v.map(&:to_i).include? 1}.keys
#=> ["ex1", "ex3"]
```

use **select** if same element can be in multiple arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
hash.key(value) => key
```

In your case,

`irb(main):012:0> tab_details.key(['1', '2'])
=> "ex1"`

Comment: The known element to search for key is not `['1', '2']`, but `1`.